# Nokogiri scraping test failing?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, rspec2

I have the following code:

```
  url       = "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dpets&field-keywords="
  data      = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

  department   = data.css('#ref_2619534011')

  @department_hash = {}
  department.css('li').drop(1).each do | department |
    department_title = department.css('.refinementLink').text
    department_count = department.css('.narrowValue').text[/[\d,]+/].delete(",").to_i
    @department_hash[:department] ||= {}
    @department_hash[:department]["Pet Supplies"] ||= {}
    @department_hash[:department]["Pet Supplies"][department_title] = department_count
  end
```

So when I do this `<%= @department_hash %>` in a template I get this:

```
{:department=>{"Pet Supplies"=>{"Birds"=>15918, "Cats"=>245418, "Dogs"=>513869, "Fish & Aquatic Pets"=>47182, "Horses"=>14774, "Insects"=>358, "Reptiles & Amphibians"=>5834, "Small Animals"=>19806}}}
```

I created a spec for `app.rb` (I'm using Sinatra):

**app_spec.rb:**

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/app.rb'

describe "Department" do
  it "should scrap correct string" do
    expect(@department_hash).to eq '{:department=>{"Pet Supplies"=>{"Birds"=>15918, "Cats"=>245418, "Dogs"=>513869, "Fish & Aquatic Pets"=>47182, "Horses"=>14774, "Insects"=>358, "Reptiles & Amphibians"=>5834, "Small Animals"=>19806}}}' 
  end
end
```

But the test fails:

```
  1) Department should scrap correct string
     Failure/Error: expect(@department_hash).to eq '{:department=>{"Pet Supplies"=>{"Birds"=>15918, "Cats"=>245418, "Dogs"=>513869, "Fish & Aquatic Pets"=>47182, "Horses"=>14774, "Insects"=>358, "Reptiles & Amphibians"=>5834, "Small Animals"=>19806}}}'

       expected: "{:department=>{\"Pet Supplies\"=>{\"Birds\"=>15918, \"Cats\"=>245418, \"Dogs\"=>513869, \"Fish & Aquatic Pets\"=>47182, \"Horses\"=>14774, \"Insects\"=>358, \"Reptiles & Amphibians\"=>5834, \"Small Animals\"=>19806}}}"
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
     # ./app_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**EDIT:**

I tried this:

> expect(@department_hash[:department]["Pet Supplies"].keys).to eq
>   '["Birds", "Cats", "Dogs", "Fish & Aquatic Pets", "Horses", "Insects",
>   "Reptiles & Amphibians", "Small Animals"]'

But test fails also:

> 2) Department should scrap correct keys
>        Failure/Error: expect(@department_hash[:department]["Pet Supplies"].keys).to eq '["Birds", "Cats", "Dogs", "Fish & Aquatic
>   Pets", "Horses", "Insects", "Reptiles & Amphibians", "Small Animals"]'
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
>        # ./app_spec.rb:9:in`block (2 levels) in '

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@department_hash` is not defined within the scope of the test.

If you take a simple example:

```
require 'rspec/autorun'

@department_hash = 2
puts defined?(@department_hash)
#=> "instance-variable"

describe "Department" do
  it "should scrap correct string" do
        puts defined?(@department_hash)
        #=> "" (ie not defined)
    end
end
```

You can see that `@department_hash` is defined in the main, but it is not defined within the test.

You need to run your app code from within the scope of the test. For example, moving the code into the test, `@department_hash` will no longer be nil.

```
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

describe "Department" do
  it "should scrap correct string" do
    url       = "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dpets&field-keywords="
    data      = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

    department   = data.css('#ref_2619534011')

    @department_hash = {}
    department.css('li').drop(1).each do | department |
      department_title = department.css('.refinementLink').text
      department_count = department.css('.narrowValue').text[/[\d,]+/].delete(",").to_i
      @department_hash[:department] ||= {}
      @department_hash[:department]["Pet Supplies"] ||= {}
      @department_hash[:department]["Pet Supplies"][department_title] = department_count
    end       

    expect(@department_hash).to eq({:department=>{"Pet Supplies"=>{"Birds"=>17556, "Cats"=>245692, "Dogs"=>516246, "Fish & Aquatic Pets"=>47424, "Horses"=>15062, "Insects"=>358, "Reptiles & Amphibians"=>5835, "Small Animals"=>19836}}})
  end
end
```

Note that your test should be `eq(hash)` rather than `eq 'hash'` (ie you want to compare hashes rather than a string to a hash.

**Update** - Code Extracted to a Class:

Moving the app code into the test is not ideal if it is meant to be reusable else where. Instead, it might be better to create a method or class for your application code and then call that code from the test.

```
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

# This class could be placed in your app.rb  
class DepartmentScraper
  def scrape_page()
    url       = "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dpets&field-keywords="
    data      = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

    department   = data.css('#ref_2619534011')

    @department_hash = {}
    department.css('li').drop(1).each do | department |
      department_title = department.css('.refinementLink').text
      department_count = department.css('.narrowValue').text[/[\d,]+/].delete(",").to_i
      @department_hash[:department] ||= {}
      @department_hash[:department]["Pet Supplies"] ||= {}
      @department_hash[:department]["Pet Supplies"][department_title] = department_count        
    end

    return @department_hash
  end
end

describe "Department" do
  it "should scrap correct string" do
    department_hash = DepartmentScraper.new.scrape_page()

    expect(department_hash).to eq({:department=>{"Pet Supplies"=>{"Birds"=>17556, "Cats"=>245692, "Dogs"=>516246, "Fish & Aquatic Pets"=>47424, "Horses"=>15062, "Insects"=>358, "Reptiles & Amphibians"=>5835, "Small Animals"=>19836}}})
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without moving all my file on the test? That's why I included it at the top.

Comment: You can extract the application code into methods and/or classes (these could lie in your app.rb file). Then from the test, you would call those methods/classes. A quick example has been added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it and tell you the results.

Comment: Thanks it worked. By the way, what's the `rspec/autorun` part about? To automatically include `app.rb`?

Comment: Usually you would run your specs using a command like `rspec your_spec.rb`. By requiring `rspec/autorun`, your tests will always run when the file is included - ie runs when you do just `ruby your_spec.rb`. You should probably do it without `autorun`. However, for one off scripts or if using something like SciTE as an editor, I find using `autorun` to be more convenient.